# PHP SoapClient Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to set private key file

Tags: php, soap, key, private

I'm trying to use soap to call a webservice but I keep getting the following error "Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): Unable to set private key file".

I'm assuming that the error comes due to the fact the the .cer file I am using only includes public key and no private key.  But i'm not sure of another way to use the .cer file.  If i don't use the .cer file i can connect just fine and I am able to call and receive results when i use the `__getFunctions()` method.  However, when i try to use other methods i need to be authorized and that leads to the problem.  Below is the simple code i am trying to use.  Please let me know if more information is required.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', 0);
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';

$ns = 'GatewayEDI.WebServices';
$auth = array();
$auth['User'] = new SOAPVar($username, XSD_STRING, null, null, null, $ns);
$auth['Password'] = new SOAPVar($password, XSD_STRING, null, null, null, $ns);
$headerBody = new SOAPVar($auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT);
$header = new SOAPHeader($ns, 'AuthSOAPHeader', $headerBody);

$client=new SoapClient('https://url/Service.asmx?WSDL',
                   array(
                  'local_cert' => 'file.cer'
                   ));

$client->__setSOAPHeaders(array($header));

$param = array(
  'X12Input'=>"testing",
  "GediPayerID"=>"52",
  "ResponseDataType"=>"Xml"
);

//this leads to private key error
echo $result = $client->DoInquiryByX12Data($param,$header);
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe your .pem/.cer file should have your private key in it:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
# base64 encoded key 
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
# base64 encoded cert
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

If your private key's first line has a directive similar to "Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED" you'll need to include the "passphrase" option when constructing your `SoapClient()`. You can also strip the passphrase requirement with OpenSSL, my syntax is a bit rusty so you may want to double check if you try it:

```
openssl rsa -in /path/to/private.key -out /path/to/private.key
```

"private.key" should be just the private key in this context (you can add it into the .cer/.pem file after the passphrase has been removed.

Comment: I don't have a private key for this certificate.  Can I make my own private key and add it to the certificate?

Comment: Nope, the private key has to match it. Can you not get it from whoever gave you the cert in the first place?

Comment: they are claiming that there is no private key, but i don't see how it would work without a private key.  If i try to remove the certificate and not use it at all then i get an authentication error.  Are you saying that you don't know of any way that it could work without a private key?

Comment: hmm can you post your file.cer, and the error message you get when you access a https URL that requires a certificate (ie, with no local_cert option?)

Comment: this is the error i get when i don't use the local_cert option. 
"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized"
The file.cer file looks something like....

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIGPjCCBSagAwIBAgIQDBPCdedfOhIfuBrYJd8S+zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADCB
vjELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMxFzAVBgNVBAoTDlZlcmlTaWduLCBJbmMuMR8wHQYDVQQL
ExZWZXJpU2lnbiBUcnVzdCBOZXR3b3JrMTswOQYDVQQLEzJUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2Ug
YXQgaHR0cHM6Ly93d3baZdTIDZO7Hp6Op9TCd2InZc
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: hmm, is it possible that you don't need a certificate, but that perhaps the SoapVARs are incorrect for whatever reason? it may be helpful to get a dump of the actual SOAP call you're generating and check with them if it looks correct? as in, i wonder if the certificate is related specifically to SSL, and not to authorization to access the resource.

Comment: perhaps, i think my comment in general was more, are you sure you need public key authorization for this? it could be just u/p are wrong if it's basic authentication over https.

Comment: Yea I asked and got another server that does not require the certificate.  unfortunately now i'm getting the authentication error.
The error is the following: "Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Unauthorized"  I am setting the headers wrong or is it that i don't have the correct user and pass?  Thank you

Comment: Hard to tell without the documentation, but I'd definitely check u/p first just to see. Otherwise, I'd suggest using "getLastRequest()" to see the actual Soap call you're making, and ask them if that's the correct syntax? http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php

Comment: I have the trace option enabled but i can't even use the getLastRequest() function because the authentication error happens right when i try to call the function, not before.  So it just returns null since it never executes the function.  Thank you.